# Using two parts format to render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In an Ajax driver Rails 3 app, I controllers that can return different views depending on the context.

For example:

```
/users.json
```

Would returns a full HTML page listing the users, now:

```
/users.json?partial=listing
```

Would returns a partial HTML page.

Now I was wondering about using a two parts format specifier, wich would change the above to:

```
/users.json
```

First one doesn't change, but the second one would become:

```
/users.listing.json
```

I feel like the partial parameter is somehow part of the format, at least of the representation of the returned data which is in a way what a format is for. Like `jquery.min.js` which is still javascript, but in another representation.

The question is how to implement this in Rails 3 in an elegant way. The idea is to be able to use something like `respond_to`in my controller. I also need to be able to generate urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using:

```
/users.json?output=fielda,fieldb
```

To filter the output.